# Can i start a new Thread for every character entered in EditText for searching

Tags: android, search, retrofit, textwatcher

Good Afternoon, I have a question please have look at this.

I am using Retrofit beta 2 for retrieving data from api. I have an EditText in which I want to search some names from server. I got the output also, but for example consider there are some names:

ABC,XYZ,PQR,STU,ETC.  These are the names stored in the server and I am retrieving this names using Retrofit beta2.

When I searched for ABC or abc it will display the results and when I removed the string from the EditText then nothing is displayed.

Till here I Have done.

My question is when I type names fast then the result is something else.

So, can anyone tell me how to avoid this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Call` object has a couple of utility methods you can use namely `isExecuted` and `cancel` to control your request.

http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html

I am assuming you are using `TextWatcher`. Pseudo-code as follows:

```
public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {
    // Cancel the request first before sending it again; this way you won't have two separate calls
    if(call != null && call.isExecuted()) {
      call.cancel();
    }

    // reinitialize call and execute it again
}
```

Generally speaking, it is ill-advised to listen for immediate input from user to spawn an action: you should rethink your approach; it's better to put a "submit" or button to execute the API call; otherwise you'll be spamming the server with several HTTP requests per input.

Comment: Ya that's correct, But I don't want my users to type full String instead they can use suggestions. and yes I am using TextWatcher in this.

Comment: Alright, then stick with cancelling before sending it so you won't have multiple calls. http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#cancel--

Answer (score 1):

Remember the search text e.g. "AB" on the search result. Before displaying the result, check if the currently entered text still matches the text of the search result and only use the result, if it does.

Searched for "AB", current text "ABC" -> don't show the result.

Searched for "ABC", current text "ABC" -> show the result.

Like this it won't even matter in what order the two requests return, it will always display only the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not safe to `start a new thread for every character`

This is How I did in my App:

You can use a Queue to store every string that user input. Every time the edittext changed, a new string will be inserted to the queue

At the same time, you can send the query async by retrofit. but if the retrofit is on its way querying, you do not send immediately, only put the string into the queue. when your callback function is called by retrofit, you can remove all strings from queues except the latest one, then use retrofit to query this newest query.

Answer (score 0):

Too much thread, will affect the performance of any device, because it the overhead involve will consume lot of resource.

starting a new thread for each character is by no means advisable, to answer your question each thread should continually check for a change in characters, when you type fast, it mean tend to skip some result but will eventually display the result of the last string correctly.